# orientdb select out().out() return two same vertex?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

#### I have a test graph below

a_1 ---[e_a_b]---> b_1

a_1 ---[e_a_b]---> b_2

b_1 ---[e_b_c]---> c_1

b_2 ---[e_b_c]---> c_1

execute sql

`select expand(out("e_a_b").out("e_b_c")) from v_a`

return two same vertex(two c_1), it's a BUG? or I used in a wrong way?

How can I get one single `c_1` after `select expand(out("e_a_b").out("e_b_c")) from v_a`on my test data?

My purpose is to count friends of friends and sort by the result
How can I get this.

I know `traverse out("e_a_b", "e_b_c") from (select from v_a where name = "a_1")`,

but this only get one of the v_a(the a_1),

I need a page of `v_a` and the count of relation's relation.

#### here is my data scripts

```
create class v_a extends v clusters 1;
create vertex v_a content {"name": "a_1"};
create class v_b extends v clusters 1;
create vertex v_b content {"name": "b_1"};
create vertex v_b content {"name": "b_2"};
create class v_c extends v clusters 1;
create vertex v_c content {"name": "c_1"};
create class e_a_b extends e clusters 1;
create edge e_a_b from (select from v_a) to (select from v_b);
create class e_b_c extends e clusters 1;
create edge e_b_c from (select from v_b) to (select from v_c);
```

#### OrientDB Version: 2.2.24

#### My English is not very well, thanks reading.

Answer (score 0):

`select name, set(out("e_a_b").out("e_b_c")).size() from v_a`

I… find the answer?

The problem is always solved after the problem is raised - -b

any better way?

the github
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/7620

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct(@rid) from (select expand(out("e_a_b").out("e_b_c")) from v_a)
```

Hope it helps

Regards